# Keep duplicated item with lowest price in csv file

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I need to read a csv file and keep the duplicated item with the lowest price.
Example:

input file:

```
name, link, price, category
item1, http://example.com/item1, 29.30, cat1
item2, http://example.com/item2, 22, cat2
item1, http://example.com/item1, 19.90, cat1
```

output file:

```
name, link, price, category
item2, http://example.com/item2, 22, cat2
item1, http://example.com/item1, 19.90, cat1
```

Here's my code so far:

```
    f1 = csv.reader(open('input.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))
    name = set()
    for row in f1:
        if row[0].lower() not in (i.lower() for i in name):
            writer.writerow(row)
            name.add(row[0])
```

I can remove the duplicates with this code, but I need help to keep the item with the lowest price.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict.get with a default value of `inf`, checking if the current price stored as the values is less than the current we encounter then updating accordingly. finally write the tuples returned from dict.items with writerow. We can also keep the file order using a collections.Ordereddict if required.

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict() # keep the order

with open('in.csv', 'r') as f1, open("output.csv", "w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(f1,delimiter=",")
    header = next(r) # store header
    writer = csv.writer(out,delimiter=",")
    for row in r:
        price = float(row[2])
        # first check price will be less than than inf so we will add the key/value
        if d.get(row[2], float("inf")) > price:
            d[row[0]] = row
    writer.writerow(header) # write header
    for tup in d.values(): # write updated items
        writer.writerow(tup)
```

Output:

```
name, link, price, category
item1, http://example.com/item1, 19.90, cat1
item2, http://example.com/item2, 22, cat2
```

If order is irrelevant use a defaultdict and min:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list) # keep the order
with open('in.csv', 'r') as f1, open("output.csv", "w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(f1,delimiter=",")
    header = next(r) # store header
    writer = csv.writer(out,delimiter=",")
    for row in r:
       d[row[0]].append(row)
    writer.writerow(header) # write header
    for k,v in d.items(): # write updated items
        writer.writerow(min(v,key=lambda x:float(x[2])))
```

Comment: Hey @Padraic, I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention that there are two other columns in my input file. The coloumns: name, link, price, categories

I think the solution will change because of that, am I right? Sorry for that.

Comment: And you only want the two?

Comment: No, I want the output to be the same format as input: name, link, price, category

Comment: Yes i meant just the two checked for dups

Comment: Hey @Padraic, I'm getting the following error using defaultdict:  writer.writerow(min(v,key=lambda x:float(x[2])))
        exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then you don't have four items in each row, does the first code run? I have tested the code with the input provided and it works well

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I run the first code: price = float(row[2])
        exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I check the input file and all 4 colums has data.

Comment: if there are four in each row and all delimited by a comma then this code will work 100 percent. You should put  a `print(row)` before the `price = float(row[2])` and see exactly what is in the row

Comment: The code is working now! But there is duplicated data in output file because lower case and uppercase letters. How to make your code case insensitive? I'm using defaultdict.

Comment: You need `row[2].lower()`

Comment: @Padric, I'm using the defaultdict solution. Where I have to put this code (row[2].lower()) ?

Comment: `d[row[0].lower()].append(row)`

Comment: Hey @Padraic. Your code is working perfectly! Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the for loop with `dict.setdefault` in the solution below provided by mu. `dict.setdefault` sets a value for a key if a key does not exist, otherwise it leaves the value unchanged. It returns the current value whether changed o unchanged.

`for row in f1:
    a = names.setdefault(row[0],row[1])
    if row[1]<a:
        names[row[0]] = row[1]`

Answer (score 0):

this is trivial in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('in_csv')
df.groupby('name').min()
```

Answer (score 0):

csv file columns are : `name, link, price, category`

```
import itertools, operator
data = list()
new_data = list()
name = operator.itemgetter(0)
name_price = operator.itemgetter(0,2)
```

Separate the header from the data.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    header = f.next()
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

`data` is a list of lists - `[[name, link, price, category], ...]`

Sort `data` on name first and price second.

```
data.sort(key = name_price)
```

Use `itertools.groupby` to group by names, take the first item from each group and format it, then save it to a new list.

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, name):
    # the first item in the group has the lowest price
    lowest_price = list(group)[0]
    lowest_price = ','.join(lowest_price) + '\n'
    new_data.append(lowest_price)
```

Write `header` and ```new_data` to a file.

```
with open('new_data.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(header)
    f.writelines(new_data)
```

Edited to account for more fields.

Comment: this is `n log n` as opposed to linear using a dict

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, You are quite right.  This has the disadvantage of passing over the data more than once - but it is quite readable.  If the data size isn't too large then it shouldn't matter .... ```Premature Optimization ...``` and all that.  I didn't see an efficiency spec in the OP's post.  Cheers, have a pint on me.

Comment: yes but worth pointing out for anyone that may come across the question and want an efficient solution. The csv module is pretty much tailor-made for this problem also